# Push from UIButton to Navigation Controller

Tags: view, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a Navigation Controller (see sketch below) that "houses" a Tab Bar Controller. The Tab bar controller has 4 tabs (views). Now, inside one of those views, I have a UIButton. I WANT to create a Push segue from this button (highlighted) to another view, but I need the view it's pushing to to have Navigation capabilities. That said, as we all know, you can't push to a Navigation Controller. How can I get around this, and push from the UIButton to a ViewController with a Navigation bar?

[image: Navigation Controller Sketch]

EDIT:

So far, this is the code used to push from the UIButton to the View Controller.

**HomeViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)favoritesPressed;
```

**HomeViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)favoritesPressed {
    FavoritesViewController *favoritesView = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:favoritesView animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I typed up a longish answer but deleted it when I realized you already were starting with one navigation controller.  Do you simply want to push to the next view from within the same navigation controller (in which case, use an IBAction on the button that calls UINavigationController's ["`pushViewController:animated:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) method).  Or, did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: That's correct. I want to be able to push from that button from within the same Nav Controller :) I'm just not sure how the code for that would look?

Comment: See code edited above (what I have so far).

Comment: Nevermind :) Just fixed it. You were right. Thank you!!